# JSch is not included in jdk 1.7?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I was trying to use JSch to connect to a mysql via ssh. According to JSch website, http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ it should work with j2se 1.4 and up, "no additional libraries required". I have jdk 1.7 installed. Howver got the error saying "package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist, import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;" when I compiled my java code. I wonder how to get it to work.

Comment: Err, no, you have misread that. It's not part of the JDK, and that statement doesn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the JSch JAR in the application "lib" folder.

Or update your system class path with JSch.JAR

in Windows

Go to

```
Advance System settings --> Advanced (tab) --> Environment Variables --> User Variables
```

Add

```
CLASSPATH = %CLASSPATH%;C:\LOCATION OF THE JAR\JSch.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, "no additional libraries required" implies "except for our library." It is not uncommon to use a library that then requires twenty other libraries (which is why tools like maven exist and are used everywhere).

Try downloading the jsch jar and including it in your classpath, and I bet the error will go away.

Comment: yes that works. But it is not convenient to add the path every time I run it. Can I put the jar to where these standard library jars files are located?

Comment: I believe that may very well "solve" your problem, but that is definitely NOT the standard practice. Better is to use a tool like maven to describe your project, and let it deal with all the details of dependencies, classpath, etc.