# How do I know that I've imported a jar properly in AndroidStudio project

Tags: android, jsch

I'm trying to use a third party library in AndroidStudio and am having some problems, it is the JSch library.

What I did was download the ".jar file
On my app within Module Settings I added it
And then selecting the app module again I added it within the dependencies

Yet when I try to code it into my files through "import com." it does not show.

I am too new at this to know if I added it incorrectly or if it has a problem within the ".jar" file.

Does this ring a bell with anyone who might know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646243/why-does-android-studio-dont-recognize-jar-library-imports

Comment: @ak1 Well, it seems I imported it correctly.  But I still can't use the "import" lines in my code.  For example the line 

    'import com.jcraft.jsch.*'

fails right after the "com." part.  So how do I know if the jar file is even good?

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690600/jsch-is-not-included-in-jdk-1-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow this steps:

1.- Put the jar into the libs folder

2.- Right click it and select "Add as library"

3.- Check that your build.gradle file contains:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}
```

You'll provably need to do a clean build

Comment: I can't point my finger to just one thing to say "this was it".  But I did start from scratch including a clean download.  And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Add library to yours app dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Other libraries...

    compile group: 'jsch', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.29'
}
```

And synchronize your gradle.